# How to create the land (hills) like iOS game 'Contre Jour'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, box2d

**How to create the land (hills) like iOS game [Contre Jour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptdTdJarWLw&feature=colike#t=0m37s)? (Using Box2d and OpenGL)**

My ideas:

**Physics (Box2d)**

1. I think we have array of bodies or fixture.
2. When we to touch screen, determine touch location.
3. If the touch location is not far from land, we begin to scan the array of bodies, and are looking for a body with coordinates closest to touch Location.
4. When case a touch Move, move the right body to a new coordinate (`body->SetTransform(...)`).

What do you think, efficient to use a large number of bodies? And find for the right body by coordinates?

**Graphics (OpenGL)**

There is an array of vertices and triangles created by drawing the land (hills)?
Is this true?

[image]

Comment: Creating it with a game engine would be much easier

Comment: Like Cocos 2D for iPhone, that may make your work easier with Graphics instead of using OpenGL directly.

Comment: Maybe. Can you give an example of how to do it with Cocos2d?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function b2World::QueryAABB to get a list of the fixtures in a given area, then check those for the best option. The Box2D testbed does this to find out which fixture to grab with the mouse so you could check out that source code. See also: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/world-querying

To move the body you can indeed use SetTransform, which would be good if the object does not need to interact with anything along the way. Another option might be to SetLinearVelocity to a velocity that will move the body to the dragged-to point in one time step. This is a better method if you want a continuous drag with the object being able to bump into things as it moves, because it does not teleport the body instantly to the finger position. If the body is a bullet body then it also prevents the user from dragging things through other objects, eg a static wall. Remember to set the velocity to zero when the finger is lifted :)

Comment: The decision to search through the AABB beautiful. Yes, move with SetLinearVelocity maybe more comfortable. Thank you.

Comment: 1) But as we move fixture? 2) If we use a lot of bodies, would not that reduce performance?

Comment: 1) ? 2) I doubt it. If you think about it the bodies are being calculated all the time anyway. Only if there were a large number asleep and you woke them up, then it might make some difference.

Comment: 1) I thought that it is possible to resolve the issue using the fixture. 2) Ok. What do you think, what kind of connection (joints) used here?

Comment: 1) SetTransform and SetLinearVelocity are for bodies, so after you find fixture you want to move you can get the body with fixture->GetBody(). 2) No idea... are we talking about joints? This is the first time you've mentioned that. If you want to move many bodies at once then I expect you can just use the same SetTransform/SetLinearVelocity method for them all.

Comment: 1) Thank you. 2) Look again at the hills, for example video Contre Jour. I think it uses the relationship between the bodies. I tried distanceJoint, ropeJoint, weidJoint - do not get such hills. Only chaotic movement

Comment: 2) I see. It kinda looks like distance joint or rope joint.